# Using QString get strange characters in the output

Tags: c++, qt, qstring

```
int a=0;
while (a<2)
{
    //infos.stops is point to one array, called abc[10]

    output = output + QString::fromStdString(*infos.stops)+ "." ;

    infos.stops++;
    a++;
}
ui->showMsg->setText(output);
```

The problem is infos.stops did show, but some funny characters appear like:

[image]

I have uploaded all my source code which is designed in QT Designer
http://uploading.com/files/eaddfaf8/bus.zip/
The problem line is at manager.cpp line 133.

Comment: Can you show more info about infos and infos.stops?

Comment: sorry i cant edit my question because only one hyperlink is allowded

i have uploaded all my source code which is designed in QT Designer http://uploading.com/files/eaddfaf8/bus.zip/ the problem line is at manager.cpp line 133

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using
`output = output + QString::fromStdString(*(infos.stops))+ "." ;`

Comment: i am buidiling using qt designer, this is the run error, look like cannot compile

Comment: Oh. I made a mistake earlier. Try the new one.

Comment: Error"no matching function for call to 'QString::QString(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>,std::alocator<char> manager.cpp 133 >&)"

Comment: no match for 'operator'+'in 'output + *infos.datzEzy::info::stops'

Comment: And what type is the array? Is it closed properly if it is a character array?

Comment: Error, no match for 'operator'+'in 'output + *infos.datzEzy::info::stops' , i have uploaded my project as below, maybe you can help me take a look if you  have time, thanks for help

Comment: Array is string array holding all bus stop names, using fromStdString, i can get the name just the character displayed is very strange as stated in question

Comment: output = output + QString::fromStdString(*(infos.stops))+ "." ;

If this doesnt work, i'm at my wits end.

Answer (score 1):

I think i solved it after a bit testing your application. The following code segment *should* do it:

```
          output = output+ "Stops travelled: ";
          for(int a = 0; a < infos._numstops; ++a)
          {
              if(a)
                  output += ", ";
              output = output + QString::fromStdString(infos.stops[a]);
          }
          output = output + "<br>";
```

Note that you have the member `infos._numstops` availlable and should use it. The `if(a)` is a nice trick if you want to output a comma separated list.

*(I ran your application and noticed that the `info` struct does not include the stop where you're starting your path but the one where it ends. You should include the starting stop in the output or exclude the target stop. Further note that the `+=` operator like in the if-body is a common way to append strings.)*

Answer (score 0):

In manager.cpp:103 you are calling DE1.cost(X,Y). This method creates a std::string array (passed) on the stack (datzz.cpp:432) and at datzz.cpp:502 you do

`c.stops = passed;`

which stores a pointer to a memory block allocated on the stack in the stops variable of your DatzEzy::info instance c. When the method cost(string, string) returns, the memory allocated for passed is freed and your output will be garbage. Never store pointers to stack allocated objects.

By the way, you should consider using const references when passing (read-only) strings in function calls, which avoids expensive copying.